# How to update data in a document when another is being created with Firebase Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a user collection in Firestore "customers/{userId}", where each user has a "uploadsLeft" field and value.

Each time the user uploads a project to "projects/{docId}", I want the "uploadsLeft" value to decrement by 1. I want this to be done with Firebase Functions. How do I do this?

Thanks for any feedback :)

```
exports.reduceUploadsLeft = functions.firestore
.document('projects/{docId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const data = snap.data();
  var docRef = db.document('customers/'+data.owner);
  docRef.update({
      uploadsLeft: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
  })
});
```

First the decrement won't work for some reason, and this will be triggered everytime a new document is created in "projects", I want it only to fire when the user creates a new document to "projects".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the [documentation for asynchronous programming](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) with Cloud Functions.  You are required to return a promise that becomes fulfilled after all asynchronous work is complete.  update() is asynchronous and returns a promise, so you can return it directly.

```
  return docRef.update({
      uploadsLeft: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
  })
```